# Give every unknown property in an interface a specific type and retain the static type of defined properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have a function that takes an option object as argument.

```js
const newEvent = (option: Option): void => {
  // does something with the config
}
```

`Option` should have a few optional and non-optional properties.

```js
interface Option {
  host: string;
  date: Date;
  onStart?: () => any;
  pizza?: boolean;
  ...
}
```

It should also have at least 2 additional properties whose property name is dynamic and its value follow the shape of `AttendeeOption`.

```js
interface AttendeeOption {
  vip: boolean;
  allergy?: string;
  address?: string;
}
```

Intuitively, I tried to just put them together:

```js
interface Option {
  host: string;
  date: Date;
  onStart?: () => any;
  pizza?: boolean;
  [name: string]: AttendeeOption
}
```

Using string index signature like this doesn't work since all properties will now need to conform to `AttendeeOption` type.

Second attempt, I tried to make `Option` and `Attendee` intersect:

```
interface Attendee {
  [name: string]: AttendeeOption
}

const newEvent = (option: Option & Attendee): void => {
  // does something with the config
}
```

The interface error went away for now,

```
newEvent({
  host: 'Professor Oak',
  date: new Date(2021, 1, 3),
  'Ash': {vip: true, address: 'Pallet Town'},
  'Brock': {vip: true, address: 'Pewter City'},
  'Misty': {vip: true, address: 'Cerulean City'},
})
```

When I test it, I got error on the `Ash`, `Brock`, `May` property: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Ash'' does not exist in type 'Option'`

Any idea on how to approach this would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You want [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) but it's not part of the language.  You can do something like the following:

Comment: [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYmQbwFgAoZZAC2wGcwAuZGqUAcwG4SyATOSegER4R2pZLgDKYOFDAB+egAoAlMgC8APmRwQAT2Fl0wAF6G4c5ACNs2ADYQtwgL4lQkWIhQBBMJBCcIEDCxcAg5kADdgdHpLGzsQPU1rWyhmbTNGFgS4Tk4oCCoqdLAmEDYSJ2ISGABXEAQgvBAIAHcAUTCIcAAeABVkCAAPH04qNEwcPAAyZAAlCARsKE4u1oGEa2q-LoBrCG1sGGQegBpkXf3DwIm1U69h-yvcNTV5UOxx3HoexXow7GBOMIanUGsgmm0OuB5O8GvRHlMCMgANrbegZUoAXXod06fgCHzwAB9kLU-DBQBBOMgHMoiCIYRMAHQwKwyRlwJLQVJssDYACq6HQ0AAwnAqBAlAkGbhGZQaIzeQKhVBReLJeUSCRwe1OmB5PgKNQ6MgAEQm07cXhglrIASQJSnGDWRZRRERV3FaooBzUxSsZAAegDom2cG0JCAA)

Comment: If that works for you I can expand into an answer; otherwise please elaborate. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I tested it and it definitely works! (except it also allows number as property name). Do expand it into an answer and kindly explain how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want.But you can use array of `AttendeeOption`.you can add name to the `AttendeeOption`.

- Option Interface

> ```
>   interface Option {
>   host: string;
>   date: Date;
>   onStart?: () => any;
>   pizza?: boolean;
>   Attendees: AttendeeOption[]
> ```

- AttendeeOption Interface

> ```
> interface AttendeeOption {
>     name?: string;
>   vip: boolean;
>   allergy?: string;
>   address?: string;
> }
> ```

- Your Object can be like this

> ```
> {
>   host: 'Professor Oak',
>     date: new Date(2021, 1, 3),
>       Attendees : [
>         {name: 'name1',vip: true, address: 'Cerulean City'},
>         {name: 'name2',vip: true, address: 'Cerulean City'},
>         {name: 'name3',vip: true, address: 'Cerulean City'}
>       ]
> ```

}